# 2002 santa fe problems please help

Tags: santa-fe

Hey i have a 2002 Santa Fe and while i was driving the cars lights went dim then radio turned off. The car started to jolt and its not the first time this has its done it but i have checked the alternator and got a new battery for it but now the car wont even start like at all any suggestions. Please help. i have been having the same problems for a while but it is not an everyday thing its moor like every few weeks.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you need to check all the electrical connections and cables / wires as something seems to be loose or broken.

It may be relatively easy like a battery cable or difficult to find like a loose internal link in the fuse box (which can get moved when a door is slammed for example).

Finding this type of problem can make looking for a needle in a haystack easy!...

Comment: Check for signs of rodents/creatures nesting in, around, and under, the engine bay, any signs of damaged wiring etc. Remove the grounds, clean them, and tighten. Look for puddling and/or staining on/around electrical connectors.